# Creating a terminal command in Minix

Tags: unix, command-line, terminal, minix

I want to create a command that runs an executable created by compiling a `c` program. I couldn't find a proper solution. Let's say I have a file named `myprogram.c` and compile it and have `myprogram` as . I want to type `myprogram` in any folder in my system and run it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does it work if you type `./myprogram` into the command line?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to type `./`. I want to be able to run it from any folder, just like `ls` or `pwd`.

Comment: Add the directory `.` to the end of your `PATH` environment variable so it looks like `<WHATEVER OUTPUT OF echo $PATH WAS>:.`

Comment: @DylanKirkby - or, perhaps, *don't* do that, and save yourself confusion and risk. Sometimes the best answer is "that's a really bad idea, don't do that, find another way." If you can suggest that other way, perhaps you get upvoted. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find out what your PATH is

```
echo $PATH
```

For you this outputs

```
/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/pkg/sbin:/usr/pkg/bin/usr/X11R7/bin:usr/X11R‌​‌​6/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Then assuming your program is in the `/usr/myprog` directory, append `/usr/myprog` to your `PATH` (don't forget to separate directories with a colon `:`)

```
export PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/pkg/sbin:/usr/pkg/bin/usr/X11R7/bin:usr/X11R‌​‌​6/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/myprog
```

Doing this tells the system when you don't specify an absolute path (like ./myprogram) to look in all the directories in `PATH`.  It is good to add the absolute path of your executable to PATH because adding `.` to your `PATH` is frowned upon by some (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default)).

Comment: Minix is a bit weird. My path is `/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/pkg/sbin:/usr/pkg/bin/usr/X11R7/bin:usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin` which is hard to understand. Also I assume in Minix the .bashrc file is .shrc but I am not so sure about it. By the way my program is under the `/usr/myprog` folder.

Comment: So change it to `/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/pkg/sbin:/usr/pkg/bin/usr/X11R7/bin:usr/X11R‌​6/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/myprog`

Comment: `PATH` is simple enough to understand, it is just a set of unix directories separated by colons.  Yours includes `/sbin`, `/usr/local/bin` and a few others.

Comment: Well I guess it was simple enough. Working now. Also, the `.bashrc` equivalent of Minix is under the /root folder named `.shrc` in case anyone needs it in future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it in your PATH from your shell rc file

Answer (score 0):

You place the executable into a directory that your shell already searches for programs, or you add your program's location to that list.

the `$PATH` environment variable contains this information. You can add `myProgram`'s location to it, i.e. `export PATH=$PATH:/new/dir`, or just print out `$PATH` and copy `myProgram` into one of the paths listed there already.